# Function that remains the same after a translation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So I have this problem:

[image]

The way I worked out this problem was with **this logic**: f(x+6) = f(x), which means that after translating the original graph 6 units to the left it remained the same. How is this possible? I told myself it must be that f(x) is a horizontal line. Therefore, f(x) will equal the same everywhere that is not in the intervals 1-6. Therefore, my answer was 3.

However, I was told that 3 was not the correct answer. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $f(x+6) = f(x)$ then the function is periodic with period $6$. This means that every $6$ units along the x axis, the function repeats itself. Use the relation $f(x+6) = f(x)$ to get:

$$f(23) = f(23-6) = f(17) = f(17-6) = f(11) = f(11-6) = f(5)$$

From the picture we see that for $x=5$, $f(x) = 4$. So the answer is $4$.

---

In case you're having difficulty understanding what periodic means. The picture below is a rough sketch of what the function looks like.

[image]

Comment: Great explanation. Now, my only question is why does $f(x+6) = f(x)$ automatically make it a periodic function? How does that create a repeating pattern? And what if it was  $f(x-6) = f(x)$  What would that represent

Comment: It is easier to picture if you consider only integer values. $f(7)$ must be equal to $f(1)$ by the rule. But by the same rule, $f(8)$ must be equal to $f(2)$., and $f(9)$ to $f(3)$ and so on. So that the points $f(1),f(2),f(3),...f(6)$ are the same as $f(7),f(8),f(9)...f(12)$. But this rule also holds for all decimal values too, so that the graph on $[0,6]$ is equal to the graph on $[6,12]$, which in turn is equal to it on the interval $[12,18]$. This can only be true if the graph repeats itself indefinitely in both directions, with period of repetition equal to $x=6$. Does that make sense?

Comment: yes I understand you use the rule to subtract 23-6-6... until you get to an x that is displayed in the graph to show you the equivalent result. However, I don't understand why this rule works? Why does $f(x+6) = f(x)$ establish a periodic function?

Answer (score 0):

From your graph, it is clearly not a constant function.

Hint:

Let's use the property of $f(x)= f(x+6)$ repeatedly

$$f(23)=f(17+6)=f(17)$$

Here I let $x=17$. It would be awesome if we know what is $f(17)$, let's make the number smaller.

$$f(17)=f(11+6)=f(11).$$

Keep on going.

Remark: you know the value from $f(0)$ to $f(7)$.

Answer (score 0):

this is an example of a periodic function, with period $6$. Ab=n example of such a function is given by $$f(x)=\left\lfloor\dfrac x6\right\rfloor$$
(it is *not* the function drawn in the question).

On another hand, the faster way to solve is this:  by definition of a preiod, we have 
$$f(23)=f(23\bmod 6)=f(5).$$